# Matplotlib | Change the orientation to portrait

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this scrip to plot 7 series in the same page. I would like to set the page orientation to Portrait. As you can see bellow, I have tried:

```
f.savefig(sta+'.pdf', orientation='portrait', format='pdf')
```

But nothing happens!

Do you have any suggestion?

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7) = plt.subplots(7, sharex=True, sharey=False)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=0.5)
    ax1.plot(xtr[:num.size(xt),i], color='black')
    ax2.plot(ytr[:num.size(yt),i], color='black')
    ax3.plot(ztr[:num.size(zt),i], color='black')
    ax4.plot(obs_dataV[:,i], color='g')
    ax5.plot(obs_dataH[:,i], color='r')
    ax6.plot(obs_dataP, color='g')
    ax7.plot(obs_dataS, color='r')
    ax1.set_title( sta+' Raw data', loc='left', fontsize='10')
    ax4.set_title('Vertical and Horizontal traces', loc='left', fontsize='10')
    ax6.set_title('Characteristic functions', loc='left', fontsize='10')
    ax1.legend('X',loc='center right', fontsize='12')
    ax2.legend('Y',loc='upper right', fontsize='12')
    ax3.legend('Z',loc='upper right', fontsize='12')
    ax4.legend('P',loc='upper right', fontsize='12')
    ax5.legend('S',loc='upper right', fontsize='12')
    ax6.legend('P',loc='upper right', fontsize='12')
    ax7.legend('S',loc='upper right', fontsize='12')
    f.savefig(sta+'.pdf', orientation='portrait', format='pdf')
    plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `orientation='portrait'` doesn't have much meaning in this case.  The size of the page in the pdf is defined as the size of the figure.  (For the postscript backend, it's actually a bit different, which is what the `orientation` kwarg is meant for.)  Are you wanting to change the size of the figure?

Comment: Are you trying to stack the plots vertically in the figure? Or set the aspect ratio of the plots such that they are 7 narrow plots tiled horizontally?

Comment: Thanks Joe! I didn't know that tis kwargs was not supported on all backends. I've changed to format do ps and changed the figure size in plt.subplots()

Comment: Mauve: The second hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're wanting to change the figure size, rather than anything having to do with page layout.  The `orientation` kwarg to `savefig` really only applies to the PS and EPS backends.  For a PDF, the page size is defined as equal to the figure size, so it has no effect.

As a quick example of what your current results might look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=7, sharex=True, sharey=False)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To change the size of the figure, use the `figsize` kwarg:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=7, figsize=(8, 11), sharex=True, sharey=False)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: or:         fig, axis_array = plt.subplots(7,1, figsize = (pic_width/7, pic_width), subplot_kw = {'aspect': (whatever you want)})